# Expectation of thinned Poisson point process

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value, poisson-process

Problem statement: Assume $N=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty} \delta_{\Gamma_i}$ is a homogeneous Poisson point process (hPPP) on the real line with positive rate $\lambda$. Let $N$ be independent of $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ which are i.i.d. uniform on the interval $\langle 0,1\rangle$. Now consider the process $N'=\sum_{\Gamma_i >0} \delta_{\Gamma_i} \boldsymbol{\mathbb{1}}_{U_i < e^{-\Gamma_i}}$ which is also a Poisson process, but on $\langle 0,\infty\rangle$. Calculate $\mathbb{E} N' (\langle 0,a\rangle)$ for $a>0$.

My attempt: I will denote with $\mathcal{L}$ the Lebesgue measure, with $f_U$ the pdf of the uniform random variable on $\langle 0,1 \rangle$ and with $f_Y$ the pdf od $\Gamma_i$. Since $N$ is a hPPP with rate $\lambda$, then its intensity measure is $\mu = \lambda \mathcal{L}$. Since $N'$ is a thinning of $N$, then it is a PPP with intensity measure $\mu' = \lambda \mathcal{L}\mathbb{P}(C)$, where $C=\{ U_i < e^{-\Gamma_i} \}$. It follows that

$$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} N' (\langle 0,a\rangle) &= \mu' (\langle 0,a\rangle) \\
&= \lambda a \mathbb{P} (U_i < e^{-\Gamma_i}) \\
&=\lambda a \int_0^{\infty} \int_0^{e^{-y}} f_U (u) f_Y(y) \, \mathrm{d}u \, \mathrm{d}y \\
&= \lambda a \int_0^{\infty} e^{-y} f_Y(y) \, \mathrm{d}y
\end{align*}
$$

This is where I am stuck because I feel I need to have a closed formula for the expectation, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Are my calculations even correct? How to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We note the following

> **Lemma.** Let $N$ and $(U_n)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ be as in OP. Then the process $M$ on $\mathcal{S} = \mathbb{R}\times[0,1]$ defined by
> $$ M = \sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} \delta_{(\Gamma_i, U_i)} $$
> is a homogeneous Poisson point process with intensity measure $\lambda \operatorname{Leb}_{\mathcal{S}}$.

This is essentially a restatement of Poisson thinning, hence we skip the proof. Now note that

\begin{align*}
N'([0, a])
&= \sum_{i\in\mathbb{Z}} \mathbf{1}_{\{ \Gamma_i \in (0, a], \, U_i < e^{-\Gamma_i} \}} \\
&= \int_{\mathcal{S}} \mathbf{1}_{\{ x \in (0, a], \, u < e^{-x} \}} \, M(\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}u).
\end{align*}

So by taking expectation, we get

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[N'([0, a])]
&= \int_{\mathcal{S}} \mathbf{1}_{\{ x \in (0, a], \, u < e^{-x} \}} \, \lambda\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}u \\
&= \lambda \int_{0}^{a} \biggl( \int_{0}^{e^{-x}} 1 \, \mathrm{d}u \biggr) \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \lambda \int_{0}^{a} e^{-x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \lambda (1 - e^{-a}).
\end{align*}

---

Regarding OP's approach, I can see that the equality doesn't hold:

$$\mu' (\langle 0,a\rangle) = \lambda a \mathbb{P} (U_i < e^{-\Gamma_i}) $$

I guess OP tried to use $\Gamma_i$ to denote a typical Poisson point here, but this is already problematic. For a random point to qualify as "a typical point" of a homogeneous process on $\mathbb{R}$, it would be a "uniformly chosen point in $\mathbb{R}$", which simply doesn't make sense.

On the other hand, since we are restricting the range to $[0,a]$, it now makes sense talk about a typical Poisson point on $[0, a]$, which is simply a uniformly chosen point in $[0, a]$. So by letting $\Gamma  \sim \operatorname{Uniform}([0, a])$, we get

\begin{align*}
\mu' (\langle 0,a\rangle)
&= \lambda a \mathbb{P} (U < e^{-\Gamma}) \\
&= \lambda a \int_{0}^{a} \int_{0}^{1} \mathbf{1}_{\{ u < e^{-x}\}} \, \mathrm{d}u \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{a},
\end{align*}

which is essentially the same as what is obtained in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! So is my approach completely incorrect or could I have gotten to the answer somehow?

Comment: @implicati0n, I added a remark regarding your approach to my answer.